# how to add map.jar into myproject in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-emulator, android-mapview

i am working on mapactivity.

map.jar file in sdk\add-ons path.

how to add it in my project??

thanks..

Comment: This sure looks like a duplicate of the question you asked about an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283398/shared-libray-missing-in-android-how

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as i remember if you choose the target to be the one with Google API then it should be included in your project.

Comment: I had a tough time figuring out exactly how do this on an existing project, it is in here: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to download the jar, you can find it here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidgooglemapsapi8jar.htm