# Android: requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing

Tags: google-maps, shared-libraries, android-mapview, ddms

First of all, I set the Project Build Target in project\properties\android. 
I created AVD with Level 7 and 8 with Google APIs, set each AVD only the SD card size 4Gb, set the min version of SDK to 7 the target SDK to 8 in Manifest file. Without success. 
I delete all AVD and recreate those.

After I reinstall Eclipse Rcp, Installed ADT in Eclipse, and Installed Android SDK, and create AVDs again.

My GPS application is worked fine without Google APIs, in the earlier version I currently implemented a view for display tracklog on MapView my app does not work.

The DDMS did not show never the eclipse.

How can I resolve this error?

```
[2012-03-26 09:27:50 - GPS] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2012-03-26 09:27:50 - GPS] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-03-26 09:27:51 - GPS] Launch canceled!
```

Here is the LogCat error log:

```
03-26 07:26:22.220: E/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
03-26 07:26:22.220: E/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
03-26 07:26:22.220: E/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
03-26 07:26:22.220: E/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
03-26 07:27:03.399: E/BatteryService(66): usbOnlinePath not found
03-26 07:27:03.399: E/BatteryService(66): batteryVoltagePath not found
03-26 07:27:03.399: E/BatteryService(66): batteryTemperaturePath not found
03-26 07:27:03.420: E/SurfaceFlinger(66): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
03-26 07:27:27.730: E/EventHub(66): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
03-26 07:27:27.730: E/EventHub(66): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
03-26 07:27:28.440: E/System(66): Failure starting core service
03-26 07:27:28.440: E/System(66): java.lang.SecurityException
03-26 07:27:28.440: E/System(66):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
03-26 07:27:28.440: E/System(66):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
03-26 07:27:28.440: E/System(66):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
03-26 07:27:28.440: E/System(66):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)
03-26 07:27:28.440: E/AndroidRuntime(66): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
03-26 07:27:39.779: E/ActivityThread(120): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
03-26 07:27:41.341: E/ActivityThread(120): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
03-26 07:27:41.530: E/ActivityThread(120): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
03-26 07:27:42.060: E/ActivityThread(120): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
03-26 07:27:42.140: E/ActivityThread(120): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
03-26 07:27:49.890: E/PackageManager(66): Package com.lkv.mobile.apps.gps requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
03-26 07:27:50.331: E/AndroidRuntime(163): ERROR: thread attach failed
```

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283398/shared-library-missing-in-android

Comment: @Stephenmjm is right, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 14):

Check your Manifest.xml.  In my case there was:

```
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

which I had to remove.

Comment: If you're working with Maps V2, then you do not need com.google.android.maps

Comment: I am having the same problem.  If I modify the manifest, I cannot test my map features.  Is there a way to install google maps package on the emulator (AVD)?

Comment: @mobibob  I assume you are trying to implement Maps V2, not V1.  Then it is part of the Play Services framework.  On the emulator it should work without a problem.  What AVD are you using??

Comment: Yes, V2.  It is a 4.2 non-Nexus (MDPI).  The about lists the kernel version as 2.6.29-gea447bb (kroot@kennyroot.mtv.corp.google.com#1); Model SDK

Answer (score 1):

On a real device to fix the `fixing missing shared library`, on some roms the `comp.google.android.map` is not present.

```
download googleapps
extract two files
system/etc/permissions/com.google.android.maps.xml
system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar
remount the /system filesystem rw (mount -o rw,remount /system)
copy the files in
do a chmod 644 on them
reboot
```

All credits to [@Nys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283398/shared-library-missing-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

mine WORKED on emulator in debug when I move uses-library tag out  from "application" element.

```
uses-library android:name=com.google.android.maps
```

In release mode its asking to be inside "application", dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

Simply there is a two way

If your project using Google Maps in your project, your test device (or virtual machine) need to google play services installed ( If virtual machine, you can install it via https://opengapps.org/ )

If your project not using it, just remove `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` from `AndroidManifes.xml`