# Android: launch Google Maps app from another app failing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I have a very simple test code that I'm trying out to launch Google Maps app from my android app.

The following is the code that I'm trying.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGMaps);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:50.08818,14.42021?z=11"); 
                Intent gmapsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
                List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(gmapsIntent, 0);
                boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
                if(isIntentSafe)
                    startActivity(gmapsIntent);

            }
```

The problem is that whenever I debug or run this code from my emulator, the intent cannot be found via queryIntentActivities.

What am I missing here? The Uri object seems to be ok and the intent itself is created properly but the package manager cannot find this among the intent activities.

And is it possible that I can launch this intent from the main activity where this code is getting executed?

Answer (score 2):

> What am I missing here?

Google Maps. Your emulator probably does not have them. You need to create an emulator AVD that has the "Google APIs" version of Android.

Answer (score 0):

look at this [shared-library-missing-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283398/shared-library-missing-in-android) I think it's the same problem (same solution like CommonsWare's)