# Android Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

Tags: android, installation, adb

I am receiving a Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] via command line using adb install method. When I use the ARM(armeabi-v7a) CPU with a Google API it works fine but I'm trying to use Intel Atom(x86) CPU for pure performance reasons.

Answer (score 4):

The intel emulator does not support Google-APIs

Feature request:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34066

Previously asked answers: [Shared library missing in android.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283398/shared-library-missing-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

The application you are using isn't compiled for x86.  You will be unable to proceed until you get a x86 `.so` to replace the existing arm library (`.so` file).

If you are compiling the C/C++ library you self ensure that you've selected the correct instruction set to compile against.

Comment: Where are these libraries? C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\platforms\android-16? That is my default pathway havnt changed anything.