# Stuck between INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY and ClassNotFound

Tags: android

```
9563 KB/s (1485970 bytes in 0.151s)
WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/carEgiri28_Nov.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```

Removed from manifest file

```
<uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" />
```

I run my app, and it crashes with `ClassNotFound` for my first activity.

```
11-29 07:38:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(5054): Process: com.mcruiseon.hindjewadipune.caregiri, PID: 5054
11-29 07:38:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(5054): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mcruiseon.hindjewadipune.caregiri/com.mcruiseon.caregiri.Registration}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mcruiseon.caregiri.Registration" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mcruiseon.hindjewadipune.caregiri-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mcruiseon.hindjewadipune.caregiri-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-29 07:38:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(5054):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
.....
11-29 07:38:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(5054):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 07:38:50.627: E/AndroidRuntime(5054): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mcruiseon.caregiri.Registration" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mcruiseon.hindjewadipune.caregiri-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mcruiseon.hindjewadipune.caregiri-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Moderators, sorry for copying this answer. Its very tough to find a answer for a real device. All answers lead to emulator. This is the only one that is embedded inside non relevant answers.

On a real device to fix the `fixing missing shared library`, on some roms the `comp.google.android.map` is not present.

```
download googleapps
extract two files
system/etc/permissions/com.google.android.maps.xml
system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar
remount the /system filesystem rw (mount -o rw,remount /system)
copy the files in
do a chmod 644 on them
reboot
```

All credits to [@Nys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283398/shared-library-missing-in-android)